# Determining number of electrons transferred

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrons

When determining the number of electrons transferred in a redox reaction is it the total in both half equations?

For example:

$$\ce{2I- + Zn^2+ -> I2 + Zn}$$

First we split it up into the two half-reactions and get the following

$$\ce{2I -> I2 + 2e-}$$

$$\ce{Zn^2+ + 2e- -> Zn}$$

So would the number of electrons transferred in the redox reaction be two or four?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is it determined how many electrons are transferred in redox reactions?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/how-is-it-determined-how-many-electrons-are-transferred-in-redox-reactions)

Comment: @ToddMinehardt - While I think that the answer to the question you link will answer this question, the questions represent two very different misunderstandings. The question you link to is asking why ions have the charges they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When determining the number of electrons transferred in a redox reaction is it the total in both half equations?

In the total redox reaction *that is properly balanced*, the number of electrons transferred is equal to the stoichiometric coefficient of the $\ce{e-}$ species in either *balanced* half-reaction.

> So would the number of electrons transferred in the redox reaction be two or four?

Your half-reactions and total redox reaction happen to be balanced, to the number of electrons transferred in this case is **two**.